# Assume that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\{|z|<R\}$ and has Taylor expansion $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Assume that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\{|z|<R\}$ and has Taylor  expansion $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n$.
a) Let $M(r)=\sup\limits_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$. Prove that $|c_n|\leq\dfrac{M(r)}{r^n}\quad (0<r<R).$
b) Prove that if one of the equations in $a)$ becomes equality, i.e $|c_k|=\frac{M(r)}{r^k}$ then $f(z)=c_kz^k$.

So far, I have done part a). I'm stuck at part b). Could someone help me?